# New sod had about 3 inches when installed. Should I mow after week and a half?

Tags: grass, sod

A week and half ago I had 2000sq ft of new sod laid out. At that time it was already long, about 3 inches.

Now it is about 4 inches.

I have been reading and most pages say not to mow until 3 weeks.

But as the grass is long, should I mow it now?

Answer (score 1):

More grass above supports more roots below.

Your new sod needs to get well-rooted into the new place it's occupying - mowing it in the middle of that process may set it back significantly.

Wait.